# Releasing gas from a bottle via Arduino - opening a valve?

Tags: power, components

I'm looking for a mechanical component that enables me to do two things:

- contain a gas in a bottle and if opened, the gas should smoothly flow out (with the same pressure as a child blowing out candles on his birthday cake)
- a valve for the bottle that can be opened by an Arduino when powered via USB

I already figured out that there are outlets for CO<sub>2</sub> capsules. This could work, but then I'd need to figure out a way to decrease the pressure in order to receive a gentle gas flow.

Do you know any better approaches? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need a regulator to decrease the pressie. A modern 2 stage scuba regulator's 1st stage can decrease 3000psi to 200psi. A power tool compressor can decrease 150psi down to about 45psi.

Comment: Per some google searching, CO2 is about 850psi.  I like the air-tool regulator idea (~18$ from Home Depot), since they are adjustable to the 0-200psi range on the low side, if they don't break on the high side.    How much volume are you talking about? 1 child's breath per actuation? 1/7000th of a 12g CO2 capsule?

Answer (score 1):

If you can tolerate a decreasing flow as the pressure in the bottle drops, a simple restrictor (fluidic equivalent of a resistor) will limit the flow but of course, I = E/R; the flow will be proportional to the bottle pressure. If that is acceptable, it is probably the cheapest, simplest, and most reliable way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the product "electronic expansion valve" to control gas, also you can control valve openness degree this is optional, then put in CO2 capsules closed box also add air pressure sensor in the box, air pressure sensor controls valve to set up gas pressure, make one hole to box the gas out from here thereafter measure the pressure what you want.
Also do you need a mechanic component to control CO2 capsule?